# Browser-based yaml editor, preferably in PHP?

Tags: php, yaml

Does somebody know an installable on-line editor tool for [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) data structures, one that an end-user could use, preferably written in PHP?

No luck on the official [yaml site](http://yaml.org/).

Open Source would be nice; commercial is an option.

> **Clarification**: What I need is a tool that shows each key/value pair of a YAML tree in a separate control to make it impossible for an end user to accidentally damage the file's data structure.
>
> **Update**: Seeing as there seems to be nothing that readily comes to mind, I'm also interested if there is a Windows or Java client that can do this.

Comment: How big are these files you are editing?

Comment: @Null rather small. A few dozen string values at most, usually

Comment: are they call key value pairs?  or do you have more complicated structures?

Comment: @GWW tree structures would be ideal, but I could live with key-value pairs. However, I'm off now (I'm sick and just checking mails for a deadline), so I have to award the bounty now. If somebody manages to come up with a totally drop-dead brilliant solution I'll award another 150, but it has to be good :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no existing tool with this feature set you can use out of the box. The only option I see is to use a Plugin of the Symfony-Framework. This plugin has a UI for editing key/value pairs

1. Create a new Symfony-Project (For example YamlEditor)
2. Install the Symfony-Plugin [daYamlEditorPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/daYamlEditorPlugin)
3. Configure this plugin (see readme of the plugin) to use your YAML files.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at *AmyEditor* which provides an embedded editor for external websites:

http://www.amyeditor.com/api/embed/test_eamy.html

Comment: Mmm, this is interesting (got to keep it in mind!), but I would prefer something that can deal with yAML structures specifically and using separate controls for each field (to minimize the chance of errors made by the end-user.)